# Issue with xml keypad

Tags: android, xml

I started learning some Android development with a beginner's book I bought recently. The first chapters discuss and build a sudoku app. I was following the app pretty well but when came for a window to display possible numbers to enter in a square I messed up. The buttons are really tiny when they display on the simulator. This is the xml for the keyboard:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/keypad" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="1" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_1">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="2" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_2">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="3" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_3">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="4" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_4" >
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="5" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_5" >
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="6" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_6" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
        <Button android:text="7" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_7" >
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="8" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_8" >
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="9" 
            android:id="@+id/keypad_9" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the width and height for the button by using android:layout_width="30dip" android:layout_height="40dip"..

For more Details check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) for your reference...